# nginx add path to url while proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have following proxy_pass in nginx:

```
upstream svnserver {
    server 10.0.1.90;
}

server {
  server_name svn.domain.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/html;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/svn.error.log;

  rewrite /(.*) /svn/$1? break;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://svnserver/svn$request_uri;
  }
}
```

I just want to add /svn path to url when accessing svn.domain.com so final url will be http://svn.domain.com/svn.

I've tried to add this `rewrite /(.*) /svn/$1? break;` but it looks like that doesn't work. Is it possible to do this with proxy_pass and rewrite?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to rewrite anything? set proxy_pass http://svnserver/svn$uri

Comment: I need to have url http://svn.domain.com/svn$uri

Comment: You need `proxy_pass http://svnserver/svn/` to prefix `/svn/` to the original URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: sorry I don't understand you maybe. what do you mean by prefix? Isn't this that what you mean? proxy_pass http://svnserver/svn$request_uri;

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
server {
  server_name svn.domain.com;
  listen 443 ssl;
  root /var/www/html;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/svn.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.1.90/svn/;
  }
}
```